# Sync Sitecore 8.1 Items to Sitecore 8 using TDS

Tags: sitecore, tds

Hi all I just want to know if its possible to sync Sitecore 8.1 Update-2 items back to Sitecore 8 Update-4. I will be using TDS to sync the items. If it's possible, is there a guide that I can follow? Its gonna my first time using TDS. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sync items between versions without issue. I have even seen people do upgrades through serialization.

As for a checklist and TDS

- Make sure you sync all of you custom Templates. You will not be able to sync an item back without the required item template.
- Don't sync any out of the box Sitecore items. During upgrades these are the things that change.
- Determine if you have any core database items that you changed. Sync those also if you have any.
- You will need a TDS project for each database you want to sync to.
- Use the `TDS 2 Rocks Connector` plugin so that any change you make in the Sitecore Explorer is synced to TDS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can Sync the 8.1 TDS items in 8.0 environment.

We have recently done similar thing. 
We have upgraded to 8.2. during this process We have synced items on a 8.0 Application as well.

As dnstommy suggested, 
You need to Sync all your custom templates. Sync the Core DB as well.